# style attribute with emberjs

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to set css properties by using emberjs properties' auto binding ?

Something like:

```
<div {{bindAttr style="background-color: divColor;"}}>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: My rule of thumb with ember is that, if something is difficult, don't do it. The reason it's not simple to bind the `style` attribute is because it's bad form to inline the styles this way. Typically, you want to separate your styles into css files and use classes to identify the dom element to be styled in your templates. So, you'd have `<div {{bindAttr class="color"}}>` then define the `color` function in your controller and create the appropriate styles in your css. There are a few different pieces involved but this pattern scales and people will understand your codebase.

Comment: Expect if you want to use background-size: cover; on an image, that is dynamically generated (like the making a user profile pic stretch to cover something). Inline styles are needed sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that as of `ember 1.13`. binding attributes (`bind-attr`) is deprecated. You would need to use code similar to this to bind to the class:

```
<div class={{myClass}}></div>
```

Furthermore, `style` binding in this fashion is not recommended because it can introduce XSS vulnerabilities. The HTML templating automatically escapes HTML to prevent XSS when using `{{...}}`, but style attributes have additional vulnerabilities outside of the scope of the built-in escaping.

The recommended approach is to escape the CSS yourself (i.e. creating the `escapeCSS` function that would escape the specific CSS appropriately to prevent XSS - this is not a built-in function. You could start with `Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression` and add any additional checking from that base.) More information can be found here:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_escaping-html-content

Then you tell Ember that the string is "safe" by using `Ember.String.htmlSafe`, and Ember will not try to escape that content.

**controller**:

```
myStyle: Ember.computed('color', function() {
    var color = escapeCSS(this.get('color'));
    return new Ember.String.htmlSafe("color: " + color);
  })
```

**template**:

```
<div style={{myStyle}}></div>
```

Reference: http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_binding-style-attributes

Comment: I'm not sure `escapeCSS` is readily available function and `Ember.Handlebars.SafeString()` only marks a string as safe, but doesn't automatically makes it safe.

Comment: Developers would need to create the `escapeCSS` function, and `SafeString()` has now been deprecated in favor of `Ember.String.htmlSafe` (I've edited the answer to make this more clear)

Answer (score 7):

Another simple way to do this is to add a computed property to your model.

Model ----

```
App.Photo = Em.Object.extend(
  objectId: null
  url: ""
  style: (-> 
    "background-image:url('" + @get("url") + "')"
  ).property("url")
)
```

Template -----

```
{{#each item in App.photoController}}
<div {{bindAttr style="item.style"}}></div>
{{/each}}
```

I got this working, and seems to be the simplest way to go about it.

Comment: This solution is much cleaner

Comment: this helper may be useful...
https://gist.github.com/Artistan/8ee82f6753dca632ca3307917b4e6034

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly like that but close. You'll have to build the `style` string yourself. Look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/sQnSJ/).

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
/**************************
* Models
**************************/


/**************************
* Views
**************************/
App.View = Ember.View.extend({
    style: function() {
      return "background-color:" + this.get('color');
    }.property('color').cacheable()
});

/**************************
* Controllers
**************************/
App.set('controller', Ember.Object.create({
  color: "transparent",

  red: function() {
    this.set('color', 'red');
  },

  blue: function() {
    this.set('color', 'blue');        
  },

  style: function() {
   return "background-color:" + this.get('color');
  }.property('color').cacheable()
}));
/**************************
* App Logic
**************************/
$(function() {
```

template:

```
{{#view Ember.Button target="App.controller" action="blue"}}BLUE{{/view}}  
  {{#view Ember.Button target="App.controller" action="red"}}RED{{/view}} 

  {{#view App.View colorBinding="App.controller.color" attributeBindings="style"}}
    Color is {{App.controller.color}}
  {{/view}}

   <hr>
   <div {{bindAttr style="App.controller.style"}}>And another way...</div>
```

Comment: Nice example ud3323! Just to be clear to the OP, the bindAttr helper (bound to a style property) could be used instead of creating separate views.

Comment: The second way is deprecated, but you can do it in the view class: `attributeBindings: ['style'],`

Answer (score 3):

Recent Ember version (2.3.0 as of this writing) allows straight-forward embedding of computed style.

```js
// bar-graph.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({  
  classNames: ['bar-graph'],

  inlineStyle: Ember.computed('attrs.min', 'attrs.max', 'attrs.value', function() {
    let min = this.get('attrs.min');
    let max = this.get('attrs.max');
    let value = this.get('attrs.value')
    let percentage = Math.round(value / (max - min) * 100);
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(`width: ${percentage}%`);
  })
});
```

```hbs
<!-- bar-graph.hbs -->
<div class="bar" style={{inlineStyle}}>{{value}}</div>
```

[Live example](https://ember-twiddle.com/80725de480370c85eb80)

Comment: Notice the ```Ember.Handlebars.SafeString``` function. This must be used to avoid security warnings from Ember. Ember only sanitizes html, not css so this is the work around.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using answer provided by @WallMobile, but it has some syntax issues. So this is the correct syntax to be used.

```
App.Photo = Em.Object.extend({
  objectId: null,
  url: "",
  style: function() {
    return "background-image:url('" + this.get("url") + "')"
  }.property("url")
})
```

Comment: @WallMobile syntax is coffeescript/emberscript :P. Yours will not work, as you forgot some comma's behind objectId and url.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen Thank you for correction, I just copied from the WallMobiles code provided above and quickly fixed the style function to make it normal javascript function. Thank you for noticing that. So was coffeescript syntax, I was not aware of the fact, because I have never used coffeescript. :)

Comment: It still won't work as you need to actually return the string. :]

Answer (score 2):

HTMLBars now lets you do this - upgrade to the latest ember/ember-cli to take advantage of the new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new addon which allows you to declare styles as JS objects and bind them to your component's style attribute. Check out [ember-computed-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-computed-style)

```
import computedStyle from 'ember-computed-style';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  style: computedStyle('backgroundStyle'),
  attributeBindings: ['style'],

  backgroundStyle: function(){
    return {
      backgroundColor: this.get('divColor')
    };
  }.property('divColor'),

  divColor: 'red'
});
```

This will produce:

```
<div style="background-color:red;"></div>
```

Comment: works for the component itself, what about in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could use is CSS custom properties.

[ember-cli-custom-properties](https://github.com/onehilltech/ember-cli-custom-properties) is an Ember add-on that binds component properties to CSS custom properties (variables). Its fairly simple to use. Once you install the add-on, the add-on makes the `customProperties` and `customPropertyBindings` property available on the `@ember/component` class.

For example, you could turn the raw HTML above into a Ember component, and give it a class name.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend ({
  classNames: ['my-component'],

  // Map the backgroundColor attribute to a CSS custom property
  customProperties: ['backgroundColor']
});
```

You can then reference this class name in the styles in for your application.

```
.my-component {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}
```

Lastly, just set the `backgroundColor` attribute on the component to your desired color.

```
{{my-component backgroundColor="red"}}
```